# How to play sound on specific audio device with C++ on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio

I know that winapi provides PlaySound() function, but how to select output audio device for it?
I want my program to play sound on specific devices, is there some way to do this on C++ on Windows?

Comment: You had already gave a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-endpoint-devices) and wanted a code example?

Comment: I'd like to see a simple code example for understanding

Comment: and check [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/), you can use waveOutGetNumDevs to get the number of devices then use waveOutGetDevCaps to return the capability of given device and waveOutWrite to sends a data block to the given waveform-audio output device etc

Comment: ma1169, thanks! That's looks like something I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this library [mmeApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/) and here's [audio streaming sample code from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/audio-streaming-sample-code)